# Deploy Django Application along with Wordpress (at suburl)

Tags: python, django, wordpress, mod-wsgi, apache2.2

In my company we have a server with public IP and Wordpres installed on it. Wordpress url is like `www.companyblog.org` and works fine.

However, I need to deploy on the same server Django application at url: `www.companyblog.org/testproject`.

I'm using `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` and `Apache 2.2`.

Here's my virtual host configuration for my Django application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName companyblog.org
        ServerAlias www.companyblog.org

        DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress/public_html

        WSGIScriptAlias /testproject /home/mazix/djangoprojects/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/wordpress/public_html>
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/mazix/djangoprojects/testproject>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And problems I have ... :

1. When Wordpress site is **enabled** at `www.companyblog.org` and Django app site is enabled at `www.companyblog.org/testproject`, I'm getting the famous Wordpress error: `This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it? It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching, or one of the links below, can help.`
2. When Wordpress site is **disabled** at `www.companyblog.org` and Django app site is enabled at `www.companyblog.org/testproject` I can access the test Django website, so it works fine.

I haven't changed the default Django application project. I didn't change the `urls.py`, `wsgi.py`, etc. - none of them was changed. I've only added `WSGIPythonPath /home/mazix/djangoprojects/testproject` to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

Comment: Do you have a separate Apache conf for the Wordpress site?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Yes, and here it is: http://pastie.org/private/kaece7lmmwenhkumtfesq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two VirtualHosts listening to the same port/servername. You need to combine them into one file; that's probably as simple as copying the WSGIScriptAlias line into the other VirtualHost.

Comment: I've been struggling with this a long time, but yes, you are actually right, it solved my problem! Thank you so much for helping me :)